# Where can I find an ECommerce library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce

Just wanted to know if there are any ready made Ecommerce Libraries out there. I would like the library to include paypal or direct credit card processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always prefer [Dash Commerce](http://dashcommerce.org/)   dashCommerce is an ASP.NET Open Source e-Commerce Application. Built using some of the latest technologies, dashCommerce is focused on providing a robust e-commercce application that is stable and highly usable. In addition, the dashCommerce community is one of the most active communities in the open source / .NET space, so take a look around.

Here is the [features list](http://dashcommerce.org/dashCommerce/featuresmatrix.aspx) provided by dash commerce.

Comment: thank you..took a while to get started but I think I have this one figured out.

Comment: another free and open source solution is nopCommerce. you can find it here http://www.nopcommerce.com/

Answer (score 1):

[AspDotNetStorefront](http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com) is a licensed ecommerce solution that runs in ASP.NET 2.0, 3.5, with C# and VB source code available. It can be configured to connect to any number of payment gateways, including PayPal, Authorize.NET, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [dotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) ... it has more that just ecommerce, but it should serve your needs.

Comment: do you have to pay for the service?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for credit card processing (with authorize.net, paypal and many others) try [dotnetcharge](http://www.dotnetcharge.com/). They also have a full blown shopping cart (dotnetcart), but I wasn't a big fan of this application.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking why werent you a big fan of them?

Answer (score 0):

Check with your payment gateway provider (Bank, paypal etc) they often supply their own controls or will recommend particular components they've already tested. You may have issues if you try to use one they're not comfortable with. I had this issue a few years back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/).  It's open source and under active development.

Answer (score 0):

One of the better .NET solutions I've found is [AbleCommerce](http://www.ablecommerce.com/). It is not cheap but is built in a modular fashion so that you can use those elements you need. It has support for all the major credit card processing include PayPal and direct CC processing. If you are going to be doing direct CC processing, they also provide detailed instructions on how to setup your environment to protect PII (personally identifiable information) and be PCI certified.

Answer (score -1):

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is an amazing platform. I've used it myself, and it had everything I wanted.